# simple algebra finding total time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Average time spent in day1 = 34.074 seconds
Average time spent in day2 = 48.552 seconds

what is the `total avg time` spent for two days. i guess it's the sum of those two divided by 2 but the answer is 38 seconds. how could that be?

Edit: let me put the question like this .
if on 1st day 68 people spent an `average time` of 34.074 doing some task X and on the second day 
32 people spend `avergae time` of 46.656 doing the same task X

then what is the `average time` combined for two days

Comment: Are you sure the average you are working with is the mean?

Comment: @Lovsovs thanks foryour comment .i have this problem of finding avergaes for two days when i know average of each days individually. what direction should i be looking as the avergae of those two averages is obviously not correct

Comment: @Lovsovs yes its the mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone caught up in same situation here is how i got the correct answer.

we need to calculate the weighted average when the sample size are different , here in 1st case there are 68 people and 2nd case there are 32 people ( so different sample sizes). now calculate weighted average by:

`(68* 34.074 + 32* 46.656 )/(68+32)`

(note: what values mean in the above formula , look at the question)